# file_get_contents always returns empty

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have had the following code working just fine until now:

```
$obj_fb = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id='.get_permalink() ) );
$likes_fb = $obj_fb->shares;
```

All of a sudden I realised that both `$likes_fb` and `$obj_fb` are empty.

If I go to exact same url through a browser, I can see the `id` and `shares` for particalur post.

What could have went wrong?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the facebook-graph-api, but it is possible that you are able to see the results because you are logged in and the server isn't?

Comment: Your browser can have sessions, cookies, headers that file_get_contents won't send, so that's why url is working inside browser!

Comment: I can see the results even if I am logged out.
However, the function was working just fine until now when it suddenly stopped.

Comment: Suddenly your PHP configuration could have changed; I can think of [`allow-url-fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) or `get_permalink()` not returning a value.